Error Loading Python Extension Module built using Nuitka
I am having a problem loading a python extension module.
The python file I use is the following:
import configparser
import os

import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from scipy import io
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import sys
import getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64.pyd

That is all. I am just testing to see if I can load the extension module. I also tried the code above using getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64 instead of getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64.pyd.
When I run the code above, this is what I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Test Eng/CyliteDevelopment/DLL/create_cameraGuidance/TestGetSlicesFromCamCalibApex.py", line 11, in <module>
    import getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64.pyd
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64)

I built the extension module using nuitka. Here is the version information:
nuitka  --version
2.1.5
Commercial: None
Python: 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
Flavor: CPython Official
Executable: C:\Users\LandrBa1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
OS: Windows
Arch: x86_64
WindowsRelease: 10
Version C compiler: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe (cl 14.3).

It appears that python treats the loaded extension module as both an extension module and function. But it is really an extension module: there is no function named getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64.
What is the problem here?
Thank you for your time and consideration.
I built the module getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64.pyd using this command:
nuitka --module --debug --msvc=latest --disable-ccache get_slices_from_camCalib_apex.py

I then ran the above code after I renamed the extension module from get_slices_from_camCalib_apex.cp311-win_amd64.pyd to getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64.pyd.

You do not use the files extension when doing an import.  Remove the .pyd.  Python will check for .py, .pyc, .pyo and .pyd files automatically.  Where did you get the source for the module?  What PyInit function does it have?  That's what dictates the module name.


I then ran the above code after I renamed the extension module from get_slices_from_camCalib_apex.cp311-win_amd64.pyd to getSlicesFromCamCalibApexCp311winAmd64.pyd.

Do not rename it. This is your problem! The import mechanism looks for a function based on the filename. If you change the filename it will look for a function that doesn't exist.

I already ran the code without renaming it:

Python responded with an error: "Invalid syntax". The hyphen in the extension module's name was the cause of the error. Removing the hyphen corrected the error.

Here is the module's name: get_slices_from_camCalib_apex.cp311-win_amd64.pyd.

Do import get_slices_from_camCalib_apex. The cp311-win_amd64 is just information for Python and not part of the proper module name
